# XenoShyft Tags (Onslaught, Dreadmire and minor expansions)

Tags: feature-request, tags

I'd like to ask questions about the games [XenoShyft Onslaught](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/159109/xenoshyft-onslaught) and [XenoShyft Dreadmire](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/189660/xenoshyft-dreadmire), but the tags don't exist.

Could someone create them or should I use a more "generic" tag, such as [deck-building] or [playing-cards]? My question is more precisely about the owner of a card when played in another player "base".

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can't actually create those tags yet because [there are no questions about XenoShyft](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/search?q=xenoshyft). Tags cannot exist without being attached to questions.

You should ask your questions and use a generic tag, then we'll create the tags on your questions. If you'd like, leave a request for specific tags in a comment or at the end of your question, such as “Could someone tag this [xenoshyft-onslaught]?”.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I asked my question here: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/45419/xenoshyft-onslaught-which-discard-pile-for-instant-items-played-on-another-play

Comment: @Thrax - One other note, the tag will be purged over time (90 days?  I forget) unless it is used on at least two questions.  It can always be recreated, but if at all possible, ask a couple questions to get things rolling, thanks!

Comment: @PatLudwig Tags are also safe from that purge if they have one use [and a tag description or wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127700/do-not-expire-single-use-tags-that-have-a-tag-wiki), so this one is safe.